# How to set the display name of Actions Pane Control in VB.NET

Tags: excel, vb.net

I'm trying to change the caption or display name of Actions Pane Control in VB.NET as below but it doesn't work. Currently, it shows document Actions I want to change it to Import Master

Please advise. thanks

[image: This is current name or label]

```
 Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button7.Click


        Try

            Globals.ThisWorkbook.ActionsPane.Controls.Add(actionsPane1)
            actionsPane1.Name = "DDD"
            Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.DisplayDocumentActionTaskPane = True
            actionsPane1.Show()


        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try


    End Sub
```

Comment: Presumably you would have to use a member of the object returned by that `Globals.ThisWorkbook.ActionsPane` property. Seeting the `Name` of a control you add to it isn't going to help. What members does it have?

Comment: As far as I can see, that text is not exposed anywhere. The `ActionsPane` property exposes a user control that is inside an ActiveX control that is inside some other host. The text you want to change is at one of those higher levels so is inaccessible via that `ActionsPane` property. If there's any other way to access it, I'm not aware of it and I can't find mention of it online.

Comment: Looking at below link looks like this can be done using Custom Task Pane only. If anyone can convert C# code to VB it'd be great. Thanks again.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-add-a-custom-task-pane-to-an-application?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ActionsPane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.actionspane?view=vsto-2017) class doesn't provide any property or method for that. Use [Custom Task Panes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/custom-task-panes?view=vs-2019) instead if you want to specify the header text. Task panes are user interface panels that are typically docked to one side of a window in a Microsoft Office application. Custom task panes give you a way to create your own task pane and provide users with a familiar interface to access your solution's features. For example, the interface can contain controls that run code to modify documents or display data from a data source.

All custom task panes that are created by using the Office development tools in Visual Studio contain a UserControl object. This user control provides the user interface of your custom task pane. You can create the user control at design time or at run time. If you create the user control at design time, you can use the Windows Forms Designer to construct the user interface of your task pane.

After you create a user control that contains the user interface of the custom task pane, you have to instantiate a `CustomTaskPane`. To do this, pass the user control to the `CustomTaskPaneCollection` in your VSTO Add-in by calling one of the `Add` methods. This collection is exposed as the `CustomTaskPanes` field of the `ThisAddIn` class. The following code example is intended to be run from the `ThisAddIn` class.

```
MyUserControl myUserControl1 = new MyUserControl();
myCustomTaskPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myUserControl1, "My Task Pane");
myCustomTaskPane.Visible = true;
```

The `Add` method allows specifying the title as you need.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, but I am trying to add this in Excel workbook and not Addin. 
Is there a way to achieve this in workbook level? CustomTaskPanes is not a member for Thisworkbook.

Comment: Do you develop a document-level add-in in VB.NET?

Comment: Thanks again Eugene but I'm trying this in Excel Workbook and not add-in project.
It looks like this functionality is not available in Excel Workbook project.

Comment: Yeah, consider creating a COM add-in instead if you want to customize the title.